# Having issues with if, else statements python

Tags: python

I am learning python and was doing an exercise for myself and I get a few problems.

1. If I type "yes" will that return invalid answer since it's looking for "Yes"?
2. Also, I feel like I am doing something wrong with my if statement even if I type "Yes" Correctly I still get "Invalid Answer" Printed.

Any thoughts on how I can improve?

```
attribute = {
    "G": "Greatest",
    "O": "Of",
    "A": "All",
    "T": "Time"
    }

answer = str(raw_input("Will You Make Me Food?:"))

for answer in range(2): 
    if answer == "Yes":
        print attribute 
    elif answer == "No":
        print "Your the Worst" 
    else:
        print "Invalid Answer"
```

Comment: In your code, in the `for` loop the value of `answer` is either 0 or 1, but never `"Yes"` or `"No"`, because that's what `range` returns. Rename the loop variable to something else, move the `raw_input()` into the loop, and remove the silly call to `str()` alltogether, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with user input. It's always a best to `strip` out extra white space. And when doing string comparisons to always bring things to lower or upper case. So start with

```
answer = raw_input("Will You Make Me Food?:").strip().lower()
```

Then

```
if answer == "yes":
    print attribute 
elif answer == "no":
    print "Your the Worst" 
else:
    print "Invalid Answer"
```

having done that, examine your for loop. You are executing the above code twice. `for answer in range(2):` but you are gathering input only once. Did yoyu perhaps mean

```
for answer in range(2):
    answer = raw_input("Will You Make Me Food?:").strip().lower()

    if answer == "yes":
        print attribute 
    elif answer == "no":
        print "Your the Worst" 
    else:
        print "Invalid Answer"
```

Addendum:
Regarding your problem about printing `attribute` in order. This is a dictionary, so it will not be saved in the same order that you define it. For that you can use tuples instead

```
attribute = [(    "G", "Greatest"),("O": "Of"), ... )
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I altered my code a slight bit for the if answer == "yes": to do this: if answer == "yes":
        for key in attribute:
            print key, attribute[key] 

but doesn't go in order from the array. Any idea why? It prints in this order: a, o g, t, instead of g,o,a,t

Comment: That's because it's not an array but a dictionary. IN dictionaries the order is not defined.

Comment: *"but you are gathering input only once"* - and overriding it with the current range value... I suggest using another loop iterator variable, too.

Answer (score -3):

Your code makes a case-sensitive search. You can modify it so it says:

```
for answer in range(2): 
    if answer == "Yes" or answer == "yes":
        print attribute 
    elif answer == "No" or answer == "no":
        print "Your the Worst" 
    else:
        print "Invalid Answer"
```

Or you can make the input read into lower or upper and search in the same case you are converting it into.

```
answer = str(raw_input("Will You Make Me Food?:")).lower()   # or .upper()
for answer in range(2): 
    if answer == "yes":
        print attribute 
    elif answer == "no":
        print "Your the Worst" 
    else:
        print "Invalid Answer"
```